# MongoDB giving results with fields values not equal to the query object ones

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I know I shouldn't be asking for help but the problem seems so weird that I hope this would save time to someone in a similar problem.
I'm really going crazy with this because it seems to me that the examples on this are so clear, yet...

Let's say the console output of the following code:

```
        dbo.collection(collectionname).find({}).toArray( function(err, result )
            {
                if(err) throw err;
                console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
            }
        );
```

is the following:

```
[{"_id":"5cd42e7cd8561b219e28ff23","person_id":4,"in_out":1,"blob_lifespan":22,"date_time":"2019-05-09-15-43-24-142"},
{"_id":"5cd42e7cd8561b219e28ff25","person_id":6,"in_out":1,"blob_lifespan":29,"date_time":"2019-05-09-15-43-24-461"},
{"_id":"5cd42e7cd8561b219e28ff27","person_id":9,"in_out":1,"blob_lifespan":19,"date_time":"2019-05-09-15-43-24-542"},
{"_id":"5cd42e7fd8561b219e28ff29","person_id":15,"in_out":1,"blob_lifespan":19,"date_time":"2019-05-09-15-43-27-381"},
{"_id":"5cd42e7fd8561b219e28ff2b","person_id":12,"in_out":1,"blob_lifespan":31,"date_time":"2019-05-09-15-43-27-461"},
{"_id":"5cd42e83d8561b219e28ff2d","person_id":28,"in_out":-1,"blob_lifespan":52,"date_time":"2019-05-09-15-43-31-860"},
{"_id":"5cd42e86d8561b219e28ff2f","person_id":40,"in_out":-1,"blob_lifespan":52,"date_time":"2019-05-09-15-43-34-979"}]
```

why if I do:

```
var findobj = { "in_out": 1 };
        dbo.collection(collectionname).find(findobj).toArray( function(err, result )
            {
                if(err) throw err;
                res.json(result);
                console.log(result);
            }
        );
```

I still get objects in the array that have the in_out field equal to -1 ?

Edit:
the version of mongod I am using on the machine where I had the problem is 3.6
On my laptop this problem is not presenting thought and the version of mongod is 4.0.9
However the collection on my laptop is not the same(e.g. it contains less documents and has only one field) but conceptually I'm doing the same thing.

Comment: Can you try `{ "in_out" : {$eq: 1} }` same result?

Comment: I will check, but if I remember correctly it gave me the same result. It also gave me the same results by changing the type of that field to string in each document of the collection and then querying with { "in_out" : "1" }